# How to call method at specific time in future with accuracy of nanoseconds

Tags: android, performance, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to send the command to BTRelay at specific time in future with accuracy of nanoseconds. I need to send command many time with delay with accuracy of nanoseconds. So for giving delay I use the the SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() with While loop. My Code for 500ms delay -

```
// store the time after 500ms
long testElapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() + (500 * 1000000l);
// loop for delay
while(testElapsedTime - SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() >= 0l)
{   
}
```

To test the above logic, I perform a test with it. My **test code** is -

```
// Log 1
Log.d( "Test the our delay logic start loop" , "Test the our delay logic start loop"); 
for(int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++)
{
   // Log 2
   Log.d( "Test the our delay logic Start"+ i , "Test the our delay logic Start 500 " +     i);
   testElapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() + (500 * 1000000l);
   // Loop for delay
   while(testElapsedTime - SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() >= 0l)
   {    
   }
   // Log 3                 
   Log.d( "Test the our delay logic End"+ i , "Test the our delay logic 600 End" + i);

}
   // Log 4 
   Log.d( "Test the our delay logic end loop" , "Test the our delay logic end loop" );
```

I run above test code 3 time.When I see the time difference of Log 2 and 3, most of the time it is 500ms but some time it increase with few milliseconds.The differences of 3 rounds as

Round 1 :(time difference of Log 2 and 3)

1. 500ms
2. 500ms
3. 505ms
4. 500ms
5. 500ms
6. 500ms
7. 500ms
8. 500ms
9. 500ms
10. 500ms

Round 2:

1. 500ms
2. 500ms
3. 500ms
4. 500ms
5. 505ms
6. 500ms
7. 500ms
8. 500ms
9. 500ms
10. 520ms

Round 3 :

1. 500ms
2. 505ms
3. 500ms
4. 500ms
5. 505ms
6. 505ms
7. 500ms
8. 505ms
9. 500ms
10. 510ms

Please tell me any other way how to achieve the nanosecond accuracy in delay.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move away from Android to some real-time operating system (RTOS). Android is not an RTOS, and there is no guarantee that you can achieve that degree of timing accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But is there any way in android which guarantees me the accuracy of few milliseconds (max 5 to 10 ms)? As we can see in round 2, the difference is reached to 520 ms.

Comment: "But is there any way in android which guarantees me the accuracy of few milliseconds (max 5 to 10 ms)?" -- there are no guarantees of anything regarding timing.